# closing sql connection and reader

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm having an issue with my MariaDB server running out of pooled connections for my SQL queries. I know the issue has to do with my connections for each query not being closed properly and so when I throw a loop of 1000 queries at it, it craps out.

All my SQL works great I'm just running into issues with running out of connections because my code isnt closing properly.

So here we go.

First off here is my function that creates the SQL connection so that it can be reused and called on without having to code it each time:

```vb
Public Function CreateSQLConn() As MySqlConnection
    Dim ConnStr As String
    Dim Conn As MySqlConnection
    ConnStr = "server=*****;user=****;database=****;port=3306;password=****"

    Try
        Conn = New MySqlConnection(ConnStr)
        Conn.Open()
        Return Conn
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

This is a simple query that returns a DataReader to the calling part of the app:

```vb
Public Function SelectStoreInventoryID(Conn As MySqlConnection, StoreID As String, QTY As Integer, ID As String) As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim CmdText As String
    Dim DR As MySqlDataReader

    CmdText = "SELECT id, store_id, product_id, product_price, order_id FROM store_inventory WHERE product_id=@id AND store_id=@storeid LIMIT @qty"
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("storeid", StoreID)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("qty", QTY)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ID)
    Cmd.CommandText = CmdText
    Cmd.Connection = Conn
    Try
        DR = Cmd.ExecuteReader
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        MsgBox(CmdText)
    End Try

    Return DR
End Function
```

Here is a part of code that calls the above and ties it in:

```vb
Dim ProductList as MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader = SelectStoreInventoryID(CreateSQLConn, ComboBox2.SelectedValue, Row.Cells(2).Value, Row.Cells(0).Value)
While ProductList.Read
    InsertVehicleInventory(CreateSQLConn, ComboBox3.SelectedValue, ComboBox1.SelectedValue, ProductList.GetString(2), ProductList.GetString(3), ProductList.GetString(4))
    DeleteStoreInventory(CreateSQLConn, ProductList.GetString(0))
End While
```

Just trying to find the correct way/place to close the Datareader and the connection each time. I can't close the connection while the datareader is open. I was thinking maybe in my query of dumping the datareader into a datatable and returning that instead.. that way I could cleanly close everything prior to looping through the data.

Thoughts?

Comment: The marked answered link doesnt help. It applies to someone calling the SQL query and closing it all from the same function. I am using different objects and wanting to see how to properly close them once finished with all the objects.

Comment: The *answer* is identical - create, open and dispose of the connection, commands, datareaders in the smallest possible scope - in a `Using` block if possible.  Your connection maker for instance isnt needed: `Using dbCon As New MySqlConnection(myConnStr)` - one line of code - is all you need to create a connection.  Make the connection string a form level var